# How to ensure dependent C libraries are linked?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Suppose I have static C libraries lib1 and lib2 where functions in lib2 call functions in lib1.  I've made crates lib1-sys and lib2-sys which simply list the extern functions exposed by each library, lib2-sys depends on lib1-sys.  The Cargo.toml file for each lists the corresponding library in its link field and the build.rs for each just gives cargo:rustc-link-search and cargo:rustc-link-lib.

My issue is that when I try and build a binary depending on lib2-sys (either as a separate crate or just building tests for lib2-sys), cargo doesn't link against lib1 so I get unresolved symbol errors from the functions in lib2 which call out to lib1.  That is, depending on lib1-sys apparently isn't enough to guarantee linking against lib1.  Is that expected behaviour?  I found two fixes which seem to work, which is prefered or is there anything better?

1. I can put `extern crate lib1-sys;` at the top of lib2-sys/lib.rs.
2. I can add `cargo:rustc-link-lib=lib1` to lib2-sys/build.rs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your experience is expected behavior though annoying to run into. The other crate could be left out of linking if it is deemed "unused" and just matching symbols doesn't cut it.

Adding `extern crate lib1-sys;` seems to be the preferred way to ensure another crate is linked.